# Trigger event on incoming emails Outlook in C# addin

Tags: c#, email, outlook, outlook-addin

I am figuring a way out to trigger an event when an email comes in inbox. No problem for the default folder but need to make sure it does this for all accounts. Here is my code:

```cs
outlookNameSpace = this.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
foreach(MAPIFolder folder in outlookNameSpace.Folders) {
    GetFolders(folder);
}
void GetFolders(MAPIFolder folder) {
    if (folder.Folders.Count == 0) {
        //this loops through all the folders but it should check if it is an inbox folder with a 
        //new email and than trigger ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler
        items.ItemAdd +=
            new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(items_ItemAdd);
    } else {
        foreach(MAPIFolder subFolder in folder.Folders) {
            GetFolders(subFolder);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I found a great article on this at the learn.microsoft.com space: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-programmatically-perform-actions-when-an-e-mail-message-is-received?view=vs-2019  -- the article demonstrates "custom actions when the user receives an email message."

Comment: this only works for the default folder not for all accounts...

Answer (score 0):

The [NewMailEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.newmailex) event fires when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. You can use the Entry ID returned in the EntryIDCollection array to call the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getitemfromid) method and process the item. Use this method with caution to minimize the impact on Outlook performance. However, depending on the setup on the client computer, after a new message arrives in the Inbox, processes like spam filtering and client rules that move the new message from the Inbox to another folder can occur asynchronously.

This event fires once for every received item that is processed by Microsoft Outlook. The item can be one of several different item types, for example, `MailItem`, `MeetingItem`, or `SharingItem`. The `EntryIDsCollection` string contains the Entry ID that corresponds to that item.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to solve actions on incoming messages is the following code:

```
currentExplorer = this.Application.ActiveExplorer();
currentExplorer.SelectionChange += new Outlook.ExplorerEvents_10_SelectionChangeEventHandler (CurrentExplorer_Event);
```